# I am getting stuck here, I just need test apex /snippet /mock for this. Any input will be highly appreciated

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I am just new to apex testing, I am getting responce from Trigger upon that i am moving further in my class.
let me know id there is a way around to get better understanding to develop test cases. Trailhead is just about the core concept.

```
public with sharing class Opportunity_Post {

@future (callout=true)
public static void callout( string json_opp){       

    string language,firstName, phoneNumberm, trialDays,companyName ;

        List<Opportunity> opp_data= new List<Opportunity>(); 

        opp_data = [ SELECT Name, No_of_Days__c, Contact_person_Name__c, Mobile__c, Contact_Language__c FROM Opportunity WHERE id =:leadID];
        String str = JSON.serialize(opp_data);
        system.debug('Query result :::: '+str );

        JSONParser parse_id = JSON.createParser(str);
        while(parse_id.nextToken()!= null) {
        if(parse_id.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
            parse_id.nextValue();

            if(parse_id.getCurrentName() == 'Name'){
                companyName = parse_id.getText();
                system.debug(' companyName :::: ' + companyName);
            }else if (parse_id.getCurrentName() == 'Contact_person_Name__c') {
                firstName = parse_id.getText();
                system.debug(' dropOff ::::' +firstName);
            }else if (parse_id.getCurrentName() == 'Contact_Language__c') {
                        language = parse_id.getText();
                        system.debug(' dropOff ::::' +language);
                        if(language =='English (en)'){
                            language= 'en';
                        }else if(language =='Arabic (ar)'){
                                 language= 'ar';
                        }else if(language =='Trukish (tr)'){
                                 language= 'tr';
                        }

            }else if (parse_id.getCurrentName() == 'Mobile__c') {
                phoneNumber = parse_id.getText();
                system.debug(' dropOff ::::' +phoneNumber);
            }else if (parse_id.getCurrentName() == 'No_of_Days__c') {
                trialDays = parse_id.getText();
                system.debug(' trialDays ::::' +trialDays);
            }             
        }
    }

    string jsonUpdate = '{"trialDays":"'+trialDays+'", "phoneNumber":"'+phoneNumber+'", "firstName":"'+firstName+'", "companyName":"'+companyName+'"}';

    // Callout
        string url = '__//MyUrl';  
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint(url);
        request.setTimeout(120000);
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
        request.setBody(jsonUpdate);
        Http http = new Http();
        system.debug('POST JSON updated: '+ jsonUpdate);
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        system.debug('Helper class--Lead Resposne: ' + response);
        if(response.getStatusCode() == 403){
            system.debug('403 Confirmed...');
        }
        else if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
            System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
                response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
        }
        else {
            System.debug('response.getBody() :  '+response.getBody());
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Are you sure you need to be using the JSONParser, instead of JSON.deserialize or JSON.deserializeStrict? If the JSON isn't directly supporting an SObject you can still create a Apex class, with appropriate properties, that you can use to receive the parsed data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I unit test code that includes a callout?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244797/how-do-i-unit-test-code-that-includes-a-callout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class that implements HttpCalloutMock. Mock respond method that gets HttpRequest as parameter and returns HttpResponse.

Here is link to the example: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/03/testing-apex-callouts-using-httpcalloutmock.html

That is what you can do for your case:

```
@IsTest
public class Mocker implements HttpCalloutMock {
    public HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest req) {
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();

        if (req.getEndpoint().endsWith(YOUR_URL)) {
            Map<String, Object> requestBody = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(req.getBody());
            //check here your request body
            if (...) {
                res.setStatusCode(201);
                res.setBody(...);
            } else {
                res.setStatusCode(403);
            }
        } else {
            res.setStatusCode(404);
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

Then in your test class just add this line of code: `Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new Mocker());`

Comment: You should only use "global" when absolutely necessary. It isn't needed here. Additionally, I recommend having the "Mocker" class as a nested class within the test class. That way its code is not counted towards coverage. (This mocker is not production code but is test code.)

Comment: @PhilW Changed global to public. However, I prefer setting Mocker as separate class to use it not only within ONE test class, but in any else. Anyway, it is up to the author to decide where to place Mocker.

Comment: @PhilW I have also added IsTest annotation t the class.

Comment: You can keep it top level and mark it with the IsTest annotation to distinguish it from being production code and still benefit from excluding it from your production code coverage metrics.

Comment: Thanks for input. 
Let me give it a try.

Comment: Hi @PhilW Your solution is just working fine.