# Creating a Test Class for 2 Classes

Tags: apex, unit-test

In order for Territory Assignment rules to fire on Account creation and Update, I have got 2 Classes working (with Triggers), however I am struggling to create a Test class for these, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Class that calls the queueable callout:**

```
public class RunTerritoryRulesCallout {

    public static void RunTerritoryRulesCallout(List<Account> AccsToUpdate){

        //run ETM assignment rules
        Map<ID, Account> AcctMap = new Map<ID, Account>(AccsToUpdate);
        Set<String> AccIDs = new Set<String>((List<String>) New List<ID>(AcctMap.keyset()));


        if(!System.isQueueable()){              
            RunTerritoryRules Job = new RunTerritoryRules();
                Job.accntIds = AccIDs;                
                    System.debug('Queuing ETM assignments');
                System.enqueueJob(job);
        }       
}   
}
```

**The callout class:**

```
public class RunTerritoryRules implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts  {
public Set<String> accntIds = null;
private String sessionId = null;    
public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
sessionId = Page.GetSessionId.getContent().toString();     
    List<String> lstAccString = new List<String>();
    if(accntIds != null){
        for(String accId:accntIds){
            lstAccString.add(accountTag.replace('{ACCID}', accId)); 
        }
    } 
    requestTemplate = requestTemplate.replace('{ACCLISTS}', String.join(lstAccString, ' ')) ;
    requestTemplate = requestTemplate.replace('{SESSID}', sessionId) ;        
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint(System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+
            '/services/Soap/u/41.0/'+UserInfo.getOrganizationId());
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8');
request.setHeader('SOAPAction', '""');
    request.setBody(requestTemplate);
String s = String.valueOf(new Http().send(request).getBodyDocument());
    System.debug(s);
}
String accountTag = '<urn:sObjects> '+
                        '<urn1:type>Account</urn1:type>  '+
                '<urn1:Id>{ACCID}</urn1:Id>   '+
                    '</urn:sObjects> ' ;    
String requestTemplate = '<soapenv:Envelope '+
            'xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"'+
            ' xmlns:urn="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"'+
            ' xmlns:urn1="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">'+
                            '<soapenv:Header> '+
                              '<urn:AssignmentRuleHeader> '+ 
                                 '<urn:useDefaultRule>true</urn:useDefaultRule> '+
                                 '<urn:assignmentRuleId></urn:assignmentRuleId> '+
                              '</urn:AssignmentRuleHeader>  '+
                              '<urn:SessionHeader> '+
                    '<urn:sessionId>{SESSID}</urn:sessionId> '+
                              '</urn:SessionHeader> '+
                           '</soapenv:Header> '+
                           '<soapenv:Body> '+
                  '<urn:update> '+
                   ' {ACCLISTS}'+ 
                              '</urn:update> '+
                           '</soapenv:Body> '+
                        '</soapenv:Envelope>';}
```

Comment: The question I've marked this as a duplicate of goes over the basics and provides some resources. Generally speaking, you'll want to create separate test classes for each class. With what you have, that's not entirely possible. Ideally, you'd want to have `RunTerritoryRules` implement an interface, and have a constructor or method that allows you to set an instance of `RunTerritoryRulesCallout` to use (a principle called _dependency injection_) so that you can write a test that says "hey, I know you'd normally run thingX. In this test though, run this other thing, ThingY that I have prep'd).

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244797/how-do-i-unit-test-code-that-includes-a-callout will also be useful here, though if you're not familiar with unit testing, the marked duplicate will be the one to start with.

Comment: Thanks Derek! :)