# how to test the Rest Callout using Stub API

Tags: apex, httpcalloutmock, stubapi

Hi Greetings for the day.

using the below code ,I have test the Rest callouts by using Stub API .Test class has been
completed with out failure but received code coverage Zero.how to test
the Rest Callouts by using Stub API.

Code:

```
public class AnimalsCallouts {
    
   

    public  HttpResponse makePostCallout() {
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://th-apex-http-callout.herokuapp.com/animals');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
        request.setBody('{"name":"mighty moose"}');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        // Parse the JSON response
        if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
            System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
                response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
        } else {
            System.debug(response.getBody());
        }
        return response;
    }        
}
```

---

```
@isTest
public class MockProvider implements System.StubProvider  {
    
    public Object handleMethodCall(Object stubbedObject, String stubbedMethodName, 
        Type returnType, List<Type> listOfParamTypes, List<String> listOfParamNames, 
        List<Object> listOfArgs) {
       system.debug('stubbedMethodName:'+stubbedMethodName);
      if(stubbedMethodName == 'returnAcc'){
          List<account> aa=new list<account>();
          for( integer i=0;i<=10;i++){
              Account a=new Account(Name='acc'+i);
              aa.add(a);
          }
          return aa;
      }
            if(stubbedMethodName == 'makePostCallout'){
               HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
        response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        response.setBody('{"animals": ["majestic badger", "fluffy bunny", "scary bear", "chicken", "mighty moose"]}');
        response.setStatusCode(200);
        return response; 
       
            }
      return null;
   }
   
    
}
```

---

```
@isTest
private class AnimalsCalloutsTest {

@isTest

private static void testPostCallout(){

        AnimalsCallouts mockDS = (AnimalsCallouts) Test.createStub(AnimalsCallouts.class, new MockProvider()); 
       HttpResponse res=  mockDS.makePostCallout();
    system.debug('res:'+res);
       
     }
}
```

Comment: If you stub a method, the real method is not being called, and therefore obtains no code coverage. You need to use a mock to test code that makes an HTTP callout. See our [canonical question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244797/how-do-i-unit-test-code-that-includes-a-callout) about testing callouts for more details.

Comment: @DavidReed You could have at least let me finish my answer (which is basically what you said as a comment); the linked duplicate doesn't explain why StubProvider is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @sfdcfox can we test rest callout by using stub API ? will it support ?

Comment: @sakthidasan No, it will not cause code coverage. The correct tool, as David pointed out, is to the HttpCalloutMock.

Comment: @sfdcfox My apologies; I didn't mean to cut you off. I'll reopen the question so you can post the answer.

Comment: @sfdcfox  Thanks for the solution . i am eager to know why it is not supported. will you be able to explain.

Comment: @DavidReed Thanks. I'm not sure I agree with the duplicate flag anyways, as this question is very close to the subject in that question, but is actually asking about StubProvider. Of course, you're the moderator, and I leave it to your discretion whether this should be a duplicate or not.

Answer (score 3):

The StubProvider interface is not the correct tool to use in a unit test involving a callout. This interface literally overrides the method being called, thus causing you to get no code coverage. Instead, you want to use the [HttpCalloutMock](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_interface_httpcalloutmock.htm) in order to get the proper code coverage whilst mocking a callout response.

We use the StubProvider in order to mock code that is uncoverable by any other technique. For example, we might need a way to throw an exception we can't generate in Apex, or because we need to cover code that calls PageReference.getContentAsPdf, and other edge cases that are difficult or impossible to test.

Mocking callouts is supported in unit tests, and there is a proper way to do so. Before jumping to StubProvider, one should always check the documentation and/or perform a web search to find out if there is a more appropriate method to use. For more details, please check out [this Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/244797) for the proper method for unit testing a callout.

Comment: Thank you so much