# How to cover the code coverage for Rest API Class

Tags: apex, rest-api, code-coverage

How to cover Code Coverage on test class for rest API, any help will be appreciated.

My API Class:-

```
@RestResource (urlmapping = '/UpdateBill/*')
    global without sharing class ApiUpdateClass{
        
        @HttpPost
        global static void updateBill(OrderInfo oInfo){
            List<OrderDetail> objOrderDetail = oInfo.orderDt;
            Map<string,string> orderDetailMap=new Map<string,string>();
            List<Delivery_Order__c> upodateableList = new List<Delivery_Order__c>();
            if(objOrderDetail !=null && !objOrderDetail.isEmpty())
            {
                for(OrderDetail obj:objOrderDetail)
                {
                    orderDetailMap.put(obj.doNumber,obj.billNumber);
                }
                List<Delivery_Order__c> objOrderList = [Select id,Name,Bill_Number__c From Delivery_Order__c Where Name in :orderDetailMap.keySet()];
                for(Delivery_Order__c obj:objOrderList)
                {
                    if(orderDetailMap.containsKey(obj.Name))
                    {
                        obj.Bill_Number__c = orderDetailMap.get(obj.Name);
                        obj.Status__c ='Bill Generated';
                        upodateableList.add(obj);
                    }   
                }              
                if(!upodateableList.isEmpty())
                {
                    database.update(upodateableList);
                    RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('{"success":"Update successfully"}');
                }        
            }
            else
            {
                RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('{"error":"There is something went wrong"}');
            }    
            // RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('{"error":"'+objOrderDetailList+'"}');*/
        }
        
        global class  OrderDetail{
            global string billNumber;
            global string doNumber;
            
        }
         global class OrderInfo{
           List<OrderDetail> orderDt { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Test Class:-

```
@isTest
public class ApiUpdateClass_Test {
    
    Public static testmethod void setup() {
        
        Delivery_Order__c dlrodr = new Delivery_Order__c();
        dlrodr.Pincode__c= '123233';
        dlrodr.From_Address__c = 'Jaipur-302016';
        dlrodr.To_Address__c='JAIPURTEL.:0141-6702708, 6702706 FAX : 6702713';
        dlrodr.Date_Of_Delivery__c = system.today();
        dlrodr.Status__c = 'Sent to Tally';
        dlrodr.GST__c = '24AAACC1206D1ZM';
        insert dlrodr;
        
        
        
        
        Test.startTest();
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();
        request.requestUri ='https://uat-restexplorer.cs72.force.com/services/apexrest/UpdateBill';
        request.httpMethod = 'POST';
        request.addHeader('Content-Type', 'Test/xml');
        RestContext.request = request;
        RestContext.response = res;
        
        ApiUpdateClass.OrderInfo oinfor = new ApiUpdateClass.OrderInfo();
        ApiUpdateClass.OrderDetail od= new ApiUpdateClass.OrderDetail();
        oinfor.ORDERDT = new List<ApiUpdateClass.OrderDetail>  {od};
         List<Delivery_Order__c> dod =[Select id,Name,Bill_Number__c From Delivery_Order__c Limit 1];     
         dlrodr.Bill_Number__c = od.doNumber;
         
   
        ApiUpdateClass.updateBill(oinfor);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/244794/81648) or [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/244797/81648)?

Comment: Seems fairly clear you need to set up test data so your OrderInfo instance can reference data to be processed in the uncovered code.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot one line of code in your test; you didn't actually put the OrderDetail into the OrderInfo object.

```
ApiUpdateClass.OrderInfo oinfor = new ApiUpdateClass.OrderInfo();
ApiUpdateClass.OrderDetail od= new ApiUpdateClass.OrderDetail();
oinfor.orderDt = new List<ApiUpdateClass.OrderDetail> { od };
```

Comment: When i tried to put OrderDetail into the OrderInfo object Then i am getting the visibility error, please find the error details.
oinfor.orderDt = new List<ApiUpdateClass.OrderDetail> { od };


Variable is not visible: ApiUpdateClass.OrderInfo.orderDt

Comment: @Wheels-Of-MySoul I missed that. Just change `List<OrderDetail> orderDt { get; set; }` to `global List<OrderDetail> orderDt`.