# Erro "Os métodos definidos como TestMethod não suportam callouts para serviços da Web" ao implantar classe/trigger

Tags: unit-test, deployment, callout, failing-tests

Olá!

Estou com problema ao implantar em produção uma trigger que foi atualizada, e ao executar o teste obtenho o erro a seguir em dois métodos que não possuem qualquer integração.

"Os métodos definidos como TestMethod não suportam callouts para serviços da Web
Stack Trace: null"

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Métodos na classe de teste com erro:

> Hello! I'm having a problem implementing a trigger that has been upgraded to production, and when I run the test I get the following error on two methods that don't have any integration. "Methods defined as TestMethod do not support calls to Stack Trace web services: null" Can anyone help me? Methods in test class with error:

```
@IsTest(SeeAllData=true)
static void testChangeUnidadeDiferente(){
    
    Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();
    
    
    Product2 prod = new Product2(Name='test1', IsActive=true, empreendimento__c = 'a0N1U000003EUqMUAW',  percentualProSoluto__c = 10, quantidadeMaximaParcelas__c = 10, valorAvaliacao__c = 80000);
    
    Account acc = new AccountTestBuilder().withCPF('191.197.557-91').withEmail('severinorenatofilipedasilva2@smbcontabil.com.br').withRecordType('PersonAccount').build();
    
    Lead l1 = new LeadTestBuilder().withEmail('severinorenato2@smbcontabil.com.br').build();
    
    Group teste4 = new Group();
    teste4.Name = 'Equipe 1';
    // inserindo acc, lead e Group
    list<sObject> accLeadGroup = new list<sObject>();
    accLeadGroup.add(acc);
    accLeadGroup.add(l1);
    accLeadGroup.add(teste4);
    accLeadGroup.add(prod);
    
    insert accLeadGroup;
    PricebookEntry pbEntry = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2Id = pricebookId,Product2Id = prod.Id,UnitPrice = 80000.00,IsActive = true);
    insert pbEntry;

    Opportunity oppOld2 = new OpportunityTestBuilder().withAccount(acc.Id).withLead(l1.id).withStageName('Proposta').withStatus('Não Iniciado').build();
    oppOld2.ValorAvaliacaoAprovado__c=80000;
    oppOld2.PercentualProSolutoAprovado__c=7.5;
    oppOld2.Corretor__c = 'a0M1U00000778NoUAI';
    oppOld2.Produto__c=prod.id;
    oppOld2.TotalContratoGerado__c=1;
    insert oppOld2;
    
    
    Product2 prod1 = new Product2(Name='test1',IsActive=true, empreendimento__c = 'a0N1U000003EUqMUAW',  percentualProSoluto__c = 10, quantidadeMaximaParcelas__c = 10, valorAvaliacao__c = 90000);
    insert prod1;
    
    Comprador__c c = new Comprador__c(Cliente__c = acc.id, Oportunidade__c = oppOld2.id, tipoParticipante__c = 'Comprador', percentualParticipante__c = 0, CompradorPrincipal__c = true);
    insert c;
    
    oppOld2.StageName='Contrato em Assinatura';
    oppOld2.ValorAvaliacao__c=70000;
    oppOld2.PercentualProSoluto__c=7.5;
    oppOld2.Produto__c = prod1.Id;
    oppOld2.DataVenda__c = Date.today();
    Test.startTest();
    update oppOld2;
    Test.stopTest();
    
    Opportunity result = [SELECT Id, StageName from Opportunity where id =:oppOld2.id];
    
    System.assertEquals(result.StageName,'Contrato em Assinatura');
    
}

@isTest
static void testChangeUnidadeIgual(){
    
    Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();
    
    
    Product2 prod = new Product2(Name='test1', IsActive=true, empreendimento__c = 'a0N1U000003EUqMUAW',  percentualProSoluto__c = 10, quantidadeMaximaParcelas__c = 10, valorAvaliacao__c = 80000);
    
    Account acc = new AccountTestBuilder().withCPF('191.197.557-91').withEmail('severinorenatofilipedasilva@smbcontabil.com.br').withRecordType('PersonAccount').build();
    
    Lead l1 = new LeadTestBuilder().withEmail('severinorenato@smbcontabil.com.br').build();
    
    Group teste3 = new Group();
    teste3.Name = 'Equipe 1';
    // inserindo acc, lead e Group
    list<sObject> accLeadGroup = new list<sObject>();
    accLeadGroup.add(acc);
    accLeadGroup.add(l1);
    accLeadGroup.add(teste3);
    accLeadGroup.add(prod);
    
    insert accLeadGroup;
    PricebookEntry pbEntry = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2Id = pricebookId,Product2Id = prod.Id,UnitPrice = 80000.00,IsActive = true);
    insert pbEntry;
    
    Opportunity oppOld = new OpportunityTestBuilder().withAccount(acc.Id).withLead(l1.id).withStageName('Proposta').withStatus('Não Iniciado').build();
    oppOld.ValorAvaliacaoAprovado__c=80000;
    oppOld.PercentualProSolutoAprovado__c=7.5;
    oppOld.Corretor__c = 'a0M1U00000778NoUAI';
    oppOld.Produto__c=prod.id;
    oppOld.TotalContratoGerado__c=1;
    insert oppOld;
    

    // empreendimento prod a0N1U000003EUqMUAW dev a0A5C000005Fzw5UAC
    Product2 prod1 = new Product2(Name='test1',IsActive=true, empreendimento__c = 'a0N1U000003EUqMUAW',  percentualProSoluto__c = 10, quantidadeMaximaParcelas__c = 10, valorAvaliacao__c = 90000);
    insert prod1;
    
    Comprador__c c = new Comprador__c(Cliente__c = acc.id, Oportunidade__c = oppOld.id, tipoParticipante__c = 'Comprador', percentualParticipante__c = 0, CompradorPrincipal__c = true);
    insert c;
    
    oppOld.StageName='Contrato em Assinatura';
    oppOld.ValorAvaliacao__c=80000;
    oppOld.PercentualProSoluto__c=7.5;
    oppOld.Produto__c = prod1.Id;
    oppOld.DataVenda__c = Date.today();
    Test.startTest();
    update oppOld;
    Test.stopTest();

    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community. Your code under test must be doing a callout. You need to set up Http Mocks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I unit test code that includes a callout?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244797/how-do-i-unit-test-code-that-includes-a-callout)